# On press of a Card button should direct to new page to display some information using React Routers : router, link, route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have few cards on my home page each one with some info and read button so if a user presses the button should be directed to a new page to read the details inside the card but I'm not sure how to achieve this. I tried using react-router but on pressing the button, it rendered the new page inside my home page. Please guide me through the steps that need to be taken.

Answer (score 0):

Use the useHistory hook from react-router-dom.

```
import React from 'react';
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import Card from './Components/Card.js';

// The parent component of "Card"
    const Home = () => {
       const history = useHistory();

       return (
         <div className="cards">
            <Card {...props} onClick={() => history.push('/path/to/article')} />
         </div>
       );
    }
```

This is the card component:

```
    const Card = ({...props, onClick}) => {
        return (
           <div className="card" onClick={onClick}>
             ...
           </div>
        )
    }
```